# MongoDB sync a specific database

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I would like to know if it's possible to sync only 1 MongoDB, instead of all databases inside my server.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're referring to [Replica Sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) when you say "sync". In that case, no, it's not possible to replicate only one database, all databases on the server are replicated. This is by design, so that in case of failure of the primary, a secondary can step up and become a primary without any loss of functionality or data (except for whatever data may not have been replicated since when the former primary failed).